# TensorFlow does not detect my GTX 1650. How do I fix it?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0

I'm trying to use my GTX 1650 for deep learning. But the tensorflow module doesnot list my gpu.
I've installed the CUDA drivers version:11.5
CdNN version: 8.3

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

How do I make my gpu detectable. Please Help

Comment: Try the CUDA/CuDNN versions mentioned in this list: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows#gpu

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using newer versions of TensorFlow as the 2.12? Not every version of TensorFlow is compatible with every version of CUDA, see [reference](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#gpu). If that doesn't help I recommend trying to reinstall drivers for CUDA 11.2 or similar.